# I created a range slider that has a value 1-5. How can I add a warning message alerting the user when they set the value higher than 2

Tags: javascript, html, range, slider, warnings

I used a bootstrap range slider and, used JavaScript for the range value to be 1 through 5. Now I need to know how to make some sort of pop up warning message saying the range value is too high if its over than 2.

```
Html:
```

```
 <input type="range"  class="form-range" name="depth" id="depth_area" value="0" min="0" max="5">
                <p>Value: <span id="value"></span></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
 var slider = document.getElementById("depth_area");
    var output = document.getElementById("value");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function () {
      output.innerHTML = this.value;
```

};

Comment: Well, you have the `oninput` function (which should use [`addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead). Why not simply check `if(slider.valueAsNumber > 2)` inside? Don’t forget an `else` case to remove the warning. You can hide and show elements by setting their [`hidden`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) property.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.